# My own Exception doesn't work

Tags: java, exception

I wrote a program who simulate a card game.
I choose some values for the colors of the card and some values for values of the cards.

I wrote my own Exception, is `CarteException.java` who have two child, `CarteValeurException.java` and `CarteCouleurException.java` depending on the type of Exception at the initialisation of a `Carte`

If the value of the color is not in 1 or 4, that will be throw an Exception of `CarteCouleurExeception.java` and same for the other Exception, if the value are not 1 or in 7 and 13, that will be throw a `CarteValeurException.java`

This is my code for the class `Carte.java` :

```
public Carte(int coul, int val) throws CarteException {
    if(coul < 1 || coul > 4) {
        throw new CarteCouleurException("Erreur d'initialisation lors de la création d'une carte.",coul);
    }
    if(val < 1 || (val > 1 && val < 7) || val > 13) {
        throw new CarteValeurException("Erreur d'initialisation lors de la création d'une carte.",val);
    }
    this.couleur = coul;
    this.valeur = val;
}
```

This is the code for the Class `CarteException.java` :

```
public class CarteException extends Exception {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected String message;

    protected CarteException() {
        this.message = "";
    }

    public CarteException(String chaine) {
        this.message = chaine;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return (this.message + " : Erreur non spécifiée de valeur ou de couleur de carte.");
    }
}
```

And finally, the initialisation of a card in `Belote.java` :

```
package TP.TP6.Exercice2;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.Stack;

import TP.TP5.Exercice1.Question4.Carte;

public class Belote {
    private Stack<Carte> tasDistibution;
    private Vector<Stack<Carte>> mainsJoueurs;
    private Vector<Stack<Carte>> plisJoueurs;

    public Belote() {
        this.tasDistibution = new Stack<Carte>();
        this.mainsJoueurs = new Vector<Stack<Carte>>(4);
        this.plisJoueurs = new Vector<Stack<Carte>>(4);

        for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
            this.mainsJoueurs.add(i, new Stack<Carte>());
            this.plisJoueurs.add(i, new Stack<Carte>());
        }

    }

    private void initialiserTasDistribution() throws CarteException {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 13; j++) {
                try {

                    //Initialisation right here

                    this.tasDistibution.push(new Carte(i,j));
                }
                catch(CarteException CE) {
                    System.err.println("Erreur : " + CE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void couper() {
        Stack<Carte> tas1 = new Stack<Carte>();
        Stack<Carte> tas2 = new Stack<Carte>();

        Random r = new Random();
        int coupe = 1 + r.nextInt(33 - 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < coupe; i++) {
            Carte carte = this.tasDistibution.peek();
            this.tasDistibution.pop();
            tas1.push(carte);
        }

        while (tasDistibution.isEmpty() == false) {
            Carte carte = this.tasDistibution.peek();
            this.tasDistibution.pop();
            tas2.push(carte);
        }

        while (tas1.isEmpty() == false) {
            Carte carte = tas1.peek();
            tas1.pop();
            this.tasDistibution.push(carte);
        }

        while (tas2.isEmpty() == false) {
            Carte carte = tas2.peek();
            tas2.pop();
            this.tasDistibution.push(carte);
        }
    }

    private void melanger(int nbMelange) {
        Carte tabcarte[] = new Carte[32];

        for (int i = 0; i < tabcarte.length; i++) {
            Carte cartesommet = this.tasDistibution.peek();
            this.tasDistibution.pop();
            tabcarte[i] = cartesommet;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nbMelange; i++) {
            Random r = new Random();
            int pos1 = 1 + r.nextInt(32 - 1);
            int pos2 = 1 + r.nextInt(32 - 1);

            if (pos1 == pos2) {
                System.out.println("Pas de chance");
            } else {
                Carte temp;
                temp = tabcarte[pos1];
                tabcarte[pos1] = tabcarte[pos2];
                tabcarte[pos2] = temp;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < tabcarte.length; i++) {
            Carte carte = tabcarte[i];
            this.tasDistibution.push(carte);
        }
    }

    private void donnerCartesAJoueur(int nbcartedonnes, int numjoueur) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nbcartedonnes; i++) {
            Carte carte = this.tasDistibution.peek();
            this.tasDistibution.pop();
            Stack<Carte> stack = this.mainsJoueurs.get(numjoueur);
            stack.push(carte);
            this.mainsJoueurs.set(numjoueur, stack);
        }
    }

    private void distribuer() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            this.donnerCartesAJoueur(3, i);
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            this.donnerCartesAJoueur(2, i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            this.donnerCartesAJoueur(3, i);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println("\n\nDistribution pour joueur : " + (i+1) + " \n\nMain du joueur : " + (i+1));
            System.out.println(this.mainsJoueurs.get(i).toString());
        }
    }

    private void assemblerPlisJoueur() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            while (this.plisJoueurs.get(i).isEmpty() == false) {
                Carte carte = this.plisJoueurs.get(i).peek();
                Stack<Carte> stack = this.plisJoueurs.get(i);
                stack.pop();
                this.plisJoueurs.set(i, stack);
                this.tasDistibution.push(carte);
            }
        }
    }

    private void preparerPremiereManche() throws CarteException {
        try {
            this.initialiserTasDistribution();
        }
        catch(CarteException CE) {
            System.err.println("Erreur d'initilisation du tas à distribuer.");
            throw CE;
        }
        this.melanger(32);
        this.couper();
        this.distribuer();
    }

    private void preparerMancheSuivante() {
        this.assemblerPlisJoueur();
        this.couper();
        this.distribuer();
    }

    private void jouerPli() {
        Stack<Carte> tasIntermediaire = new Stack<Carte>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Carte carte = this.mainsJoueurs.get(i).peek();
            Stack<Carte> stack = this.mainsJoueurs.get(i);
            stack.pop();
            this.mainsJoueurs.set(i, stack);
            tasIntermediaire.push(carte);
        }

        Random r = new Random();
        int gagnant = 0 + r.nextInt(4 - 0);
        System.out.println("Le joueur " + (gagnant+1) + " a gagné ce pli");

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Carte carte = tasIntermediaire.peek();
            tasIntermediaire.pop();
            Stack<Carte> stack = this.plisJoueurs.get(gagnant);
            stack.push(carte);
            this.plisJoueurs.set(gagnant, stack);
        }
        System.out.println("Pli du joueur " + (gagnant+1));
        System.out.println(this.plisJoueurs.get(gagnant).toString());
    }

    private void jouerManche(int nbPlis) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= nbPlis; i++) {
            System.out.println("\n\nPli numéro : " + i);
            this.jouerPli();
        }
        this.preparerMancheSuivante();
    }

    public void jouerPartie(int nbManches) throws CarteException {
        try {
            this.preparerPremiereManche();
        }
        catch(CarteException CE) {
            System.err.println("Erreur d'initialisation de la première manche");
            throw CE;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= nbManches; i++) {
            System.out.println("\n\nManche numéro : " + i);
            this.jouerManche(8);
        }
        System.out.println("Jeu terminé");
    }
}
```

The problem is in `Belote.java`, Eclipse send me an error like this here `catch(CarteException CE)` :

Unreachable catch block for CarteException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

But i put right : `public Carte(int coul, int val) throws CarteException` in the first class so don't understand the problem.

I wrote the class `CarteValeurException.java` and `CarteCouleurException.java` but that is practically the same than `CarteException.java` so that's why i don't put the code of the class right here.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you add the code from Belote.java where you call `initialiserTasDistribution` ?

Comment: Just remove the Throws CarteException from 'private void initialiserTasDistribution() throws CarteException'

Comment: @Slimu Added the complete code from `Belote.java`

Comment: @Alboz That's change nothing :/

Comment: Man, whatever nationality you are please, please code in english. My eyes are bleeding. (@Michael here we go :))

Comment: @Rouliente it changes everything :). You cannot use throws and catch without re-throwing the Exception inside your catch.

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me in Intellij IDEA. Maybe it's a setting from the Eclipse where instead of issuing a warning, it throws a compilation exception?

Comment: @Alboz Yeah i understand, but my compilation doesn't work with or not ^^

Comment: @Slimu Exactly, the error was : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem`

Comment: See the first answer from here to see what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124788/java-unresolved-compilation-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your method is declared to propagate the exception higher up the call stack:

```
private void initialiserTasDistribution() throws CarteException {
```

This means that whoever calls the method `initialiserTasDistribution` will have to handle this exception instead (or do the same and propagate it even higher). It is a form of deferring responsibility. It's saying "I'm not going to handle this error, someone else can".

This directly contradicts the implementation of your method because you *do* in fact handle the error.

```
try {
    this.tasDistibution.push(new Carte(i,j));
}
catch(CarteException CE) {
    System.err.println("Erreur : " + CE);
}
```

If you change your method signature to remove the `throws` declaration, you should be okay:

```
private void initialiserTasDistribution() {
```

Comment: Ok now i understand my mistake, but the problem is not resolved instead i remove the second throws .. Maybe a problem in the compilation settings in Eclipse ?

Comment: It seems possible. Your code does actually compile properly for me, with or without my suggested change. I would advise you do a full clean and rebuild of your project.

Comment: Ok that's Eclipse for sure, i tried my program on a second PC, and it's work perfectly .. still ty for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have to throw or catch your exception.

The signature of your method is:

```
private void initialiserTasDistribution() throws CarteException
```

So when the exception is trowed from the constructor in Carte is re-throwed by your method. Thus the catch is unreachable. You have to chose the best approach for your code.
Here a set of rules of thumb: [Throws or try+catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203297/throws-or-trycatch)